# How to set a field on an invoice after sourcing from a customer record using Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have the following scenario:

There is a custom field on the invoice record called 'contract description' (id:'custbody_contract_description_invoice')

The value for this should equal the value of the 'contract description' field which sits on the project record

Every time the end user selects a project on the invoice (at the header level), this should set the value of the contract description field.

The following script achieves this:

```js
        /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType ClientScript
     */
    define(["N/search"], function (search) {
      // function fieldChanged(context) {
    
      // }
    
      function postSourcing(context) {
        var customerRecord = context.currentRecord;
    
        if (context.fieldId == "job") {
          var projectId = customerRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "job" });
          log.debug("projectid", projectId);
          var jobSearchObj = search.create({
            type: "job",
            filters: [["internalidnumber", "equalto", projectId]],
            columns: [
              search.createColumn({
                name: "custentity_contract_desc_project",
                label: "Contract Description",
              }),
              search.createColumn({
                name: "entityid",
                join: "customer",
                label: "Name",
              }),
            ],
          });
    
          var firstResult = jobSearchObj.run().getRange({
            start: 0,
            end: 1,
          })[0];
    
          log.debug("firstresult", firstResult);
          var contractDescription = firstResult.getValue(firstResult.columns[0]);
          log.debug("contract description", contractDescription);
    
          var invoiceContract = customerRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: "custbody_contract_desc_invoice",
            value: contractDescription,
          });
          log.debug("customer contract", invoiceContract);
        }
      }
    
      return {
        postSourcing: postSourcing,
      };
    });
```

However, this is creating issues with the record loading time when the customer field is changed.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result? (different script type for example)

The record set up is (in this example):
Customer: ABC Marketing
Sub Customer: ABC Marketing Subcustomer
Project (which is a project of the subcustomer and not the parent customer): ABC Marketing Subcustomer
The main customer
[image: Customer]
The subcustomer:
[image: subcustomer]

The project
[image: project]

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use custom field default sourcing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for scripting. Just set up the sourcing for your custom field.

[image: NetSuite Field Record]

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I had not stored value on the project record so it was not sourcing correctly. I will test it again after setting the contract description on the project record (using a script) so now the invoice record sources correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to reference the contents of the field during the time the user is editing the record, you could set the value on either `beforeSubmit` or on `afterSubmit` in a User Event Script.  That would run on the server side, so would be faster than running on the client side like a Client Script.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I was thinking a client script since I would need it to change as the user input changes for the project